# Mongoose Model.find() hangs when not connected to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm going through a few error scenarios, trying to understand how to handle those.

In the case where there is no database connection, a Mongoose `Model.find(...)` call seems to hang. Below the example code. I would have assumed that the callback is invoked with an `err` object, but it is not.

How can I prevent the model call to hang? Do I manually have to check the `readyState` each time I access a model?

```
// app.js
// Let's use a non-existing host so connecting fails:
// (callback is invoked with err object)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhostXXX/blog', function(err){ ... });

BlogPost  = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);

// api.js
exports.list_posts = function(req, res) {

    // Ready state is '0' = disconnected (since we used a wrong hostname)   
    console.log('DB ready state: ' + BlogPost.db.readyState);

    // This will not invoke the callback:
    BlogPost.find(function(err, threads) {
        // Never called...
    });
 }
```

Comment: Show the code that implements the `find` method that you're calling on `BlogPost`.

Comment: @ebohlman `BlogPost` is a mongoose model (I updated the code).

Answer (score 6):

It is not an answer, but hope it will help you to find solution. Had very similar issue with 
*mongoose.createConnection*
while using passport module, found out that it works fine with
*mongoose.connect*

Comment: I'd give this a +100 if I could. I've been trying to solve this problem for hours.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I wouldn't have been able to figure out for years. This answers explains the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect#answer-22838614. And I've just submitted an issue https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4413

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already using an error handler in the connect call, a sensible thing would be to quit your app when the DB is not up, or activate some middleware that responds with a pretty `500 Internal Server Error`.

Mongoose uses `node-mongodb-native` under the hood for connections to mongodb, you might find other useful connection options in there. :)

EDIT: try setting `socketOptions.socketTimeoutMS`. Apparently there is no default timeout set. See http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html.

I don't have node on my work machine to try out the exact syntax for you, but you will probably have to use `mongoose.Connection`, which has an `open()` method that accepts options to pass through to `node-mongodb-native`. I don't think `mongoose.connect()` accepts these options, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What about the case where the database goes down after the server has been started? The initial connection will succeed, but wouldn't later calls to `find()` block as I described above?

Comment: i've done a little more research, see edit. but take this with a grain of salt until I can test your problem later. :)

Comment: As I understand it, mongo/mongoose is buffering the `find` until the db reconnects. I believe default options it will attempt to auto-reconnect. In the particular OP example, you want need to check you had a valid initial connection.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem you need to do 3 tasks:

1. Configure the bufferMaxEntries:0   in the options.db section  (for more details see [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connection_failures/))
   So when disable bufferMaxEntries this causes mongoose to stop buffer commands and retrying to send them when the server is down.
2. Configure the autoReconnect:false  in the options.db section 
   disable autoReconnet in the db level. (see more information [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connection_failures/))
3. if you are working with mongodb replicaset then you need to disable bufferCommands in the schema level (for each schema you create)

   var schema = new Schema({..}, { bufferCommands: false });