# Queries hang when using mongoose.createConnection() vs mongoose.connect()

Tags: express, mongoose, kraken.js

Works:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = function() {
  return {
    config: function(conf) {
      mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + conf.host + '/' + conf.database);
      var db = mongoose.connection;
      db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
      db.once('open', function callback() {
        console.log('db connection open');
      });
    }
  };
};

module.exports = db();
```

Doesn't work:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = function() {
  return {
    config: function(conf) {
      var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://' + conf.host + '/' + conf.database);
      db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
      db.once('open', function callback() {
        console.log('db connection open');
      });
    }
  };
};

module.exports = db();
```

Insert code:

```
'use strict';


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = mongoose.model('User'),
p = require('../lib/promise');

...
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
  res.format({
    json: function () {
      //extract the user from the req
      try {
        var user = new User();
        user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
        user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
        user.userName = req.body.userName;
        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.email = req.body.email;

        user.save(function(err, data) {
        //omitted
...
```

Answer (score 91):

Unfortunately, this isn't a simple refactor.

**1) `.createConnection` vs `.connect`**

When using `.createConnection`, you access models via the explicit connection you create with this call.

This means that instead of `User = mongoose.model(...)` you need `User = db.model(...)`.

Examples ([one](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/37309147906/why-arent-my-models-returning-from-their-queries-in), [two](http://www.nodejsnotes.com/2013/05/mongoose-and-multiple-database.html), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162979/confusion-between-mongoose-connection-and-mongoose-createconnection), [four](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1147)) show this isn't complicated but the change is subtle enough that [many people miss it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/30Dopgbsd98). The docs aren't super clear on this either, which is probably the root cause.

**2) your kraken app & `.createConnection`**

If you are building on one of the kraken examples, you'll need to make several changes.

1. Change the code around `.createConnection` so you can access the object that is returned.  In the current form, you are returning an object with a `config` function but you don't return the connection object that `.createConnection` generates.
2. Update `index.js` if you change the way you configure/create the connection in `db.config`.  You might be able to avoid this, but I suspect you'll rewrite the entire `db.js` around the new call.
3. Make sure code/controllers working with models have access to the object your `.createConnection` returned.  This means both a way to access the object and changing anyplace you set a variable so it uses the format `var xyz = db.model('XYZ')`, etc.

Sorry that there isn't a simple one-line answer...

Comment: Thank you so much, was driving myself crazy with this one. I agree that the documentation causes much of the problem.

Comment: This is why MongoDB and Mongoose gets bad rep.

Comment: There are indeed many questions around with this exact problem! I've just submitted an issue on github as this creates too many frustrations https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4413

Comment: as normal, I always use  mongoose.model('ModelName', schemaName) and export this model to use at other files. If use db.model('ModelName'), how I can reuse old code? And I have to always pass db via parameter to function and use db.model('ModelName') each time action to db ? I very inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  .createConnection, NOT  .connect

BAD:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
var MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));
// Works
MyModel.findOne(function(error, result) { /* ... */ });
```

GOOD:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp',
                                           {useNewUrlParser: true});
var MyModel = connection.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));
// Works
MyModel.findOne(function(error, result) { /* ... */ });
```

original post: https://dev.to/maixuanhan/stop-using-the-mongoose-s-default-connection-4nnj

I have a video on my channel on how to do it: https://youtu.be/mvot9o0BgU8