# Mongodb not saving through express.js

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

OS is Os X. I installed mongodb through brew.

I open a terminal and enter

```
mongod
```

A few rows are then printed in the terminal. DB seems definitely up and running. I see for example:

```
db version v3.4.3
waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I then open another terminal and enter

```
mongo
```

I see then:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.3
```

I then type in this terminal

```
show dbs
```

And I see:

```
admin  0.000GB
api    0.000GB
local  0.000GB
```

So I enter

```
use api
db.movie.find();
```

The terminal prints:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f34b96d7eac221145a5d4e"), "name" : "tutorials point" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f367e198554c65c4a34c9f"), "name" : "lalaland" }
```

I enter:

```
db.movie.insert({ name: "forreste gump"});
```

and then the find() command returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f34b96d7eac221145a5d4e"), "name" : "tutorials point" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f367e198554c65c4a34c9f"), "name" : "lalaland" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f369259a667b015582e4b8"), "name" : "forreste gump" }
```

Now, I create a new node app with express.js. This is the code:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/api');

connection.on('open', function() {
    console.log('opened');
});

var movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
var pulp = new Movie({ name: 'pulp fiction' });
pulp.save(function (err, fluffy) {
    if (err){
        console.error("Error:");
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.error('inside save');
});
console.log('pulp.name');
console.log(pulp.name);
```

In package.json I entered

```
"mongoose": "~4.9.4",
```

and then run npm install (I can see that version has been installed)

So, when I start the app with

```
node app.js
```

In the terminal I see

```
pulp.name
pulp fiction
opened
```

This means that the line "pulp.save" is never excecuted. Or, probably, is stopped by some error that doesnt show up.
Im getting crazy on this. I really don't know what the problem is. mongod is up and running, I connect to the right database in mongoose. But still cannot save a document and, most important, I don't see any trace of errors. Which apparently must occur somewhere.
How can I debug deeply the mongoose operations?

PS: When I go to terminal where I run mongo client, and I type:

```
db.movie.find()
```

I only see

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f34b96d7eac221145a5d4e"), "name" : "tutorials point" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f367e198554c65c4a34c9f"), "name" : "lalaland" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f369259a667b015582e4b8"), "name" : "forreste gump" }
```

So "Pulp fiction" was never added.

Comment: `Movie` vs `movie` maybe?

Comment: empty result in mongo client with db.Movie.find();

Comment: Using right db?

Comment: I entered all the details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is `mongoose.connect()` vs `mongoose.createConnection()` (Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect))

Basically works as follows:
When using`mongoose.createConnection()` you have to do:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(...)
// And use the db variable
var Model = db.model(...); // etc...
```

Instead of using `mongoose.model(...)`.

This is because by using `mongoose.createConnection()` you're not creating a connection on the `mongoose` object, only inside the scope of the `db` object.