# Not able to save a model in mongoDB server with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Schema which is in models/adder folder:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var schema = new Schema({
title: { type: String, required: true },
image: { type: String, required: true },
url: { type: String, required: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Now this is my index.js where all the routes have been made for get, post and delete:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/adder');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection('localhost:27017/replica');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('partials/index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.get('/adder', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('adder/adder')
})
router.post('/added', function(req, res, next) {
var products = new Product({
    title: req.body.title,
    image: req.body.image,
    url: req.body.url
});
products.save(function(err, done) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('that have been saved')
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});

});

 module.exports = router;
```

Now whenever i am submiting the fourm **products** have all the data i entered I had consoled it and i am able to make conenction with my local mongoDB server. But i am not able to use save function. Can anyone guide me how to save the data which is in **products** .

Comment: Try calling `mongoose.connect` instead of `mongoose.createConnection`

Comment: thanks i think that worked

Comment: so ` createConnection() ` just helps to create a connection nothing else?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect