# Express js moongose findOne is not calling?

Tags: express, mongoose

Hi I'm using mongoose along with express js. I have created schema and tried to find. Here is my code

```
app.post('/createAccount',function (req,res,next){

        var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
        console.log('Phone number:'+phoneNumber);
        Account.findOne({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber }, function(err, user) {
            console.log("find");
            if (user) {
                console.log('User:'+JSON.stringify(user));
                //res.send('Phone number is taken, please choose another username!');
            }else if(err){
                console.log('Error:'+JSON.stringify(err));
            }else {
                console.log('New number');
                //return next(); // go to next middleware
            }
        });
});
```

Problem is it logs phone number but it doesn't show any logs inside findOne(). What I'm doing wrong here. Please some one show me right direcion. Thank you.

Comment: What is your Account schema?

Comment: Karthik showed me the solution I should used connect to connect to mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be use createConnection instead of connect please find the difference here [Queries hang when using mongoose.createConnection() vs mongoose.connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect)

Comment: Thank you. But it showed connect is deprecated so only I used createConnection