# MongoDB insert one bufferr 10000 Error Not able to save data in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**I have checked all these things :-**

- Ip whitelist
- Async funtion try catch
- Account password
- Nodejs version

**Now still I am getting the error**

**Mongo connection code**

```
  const connectDB = async() =>{
    await mongoose.createConnection(URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,   })   
 .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

**Post request**

```
connectDB();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(cor());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.post('/shorturl',async (req,res)=>{
  let shortUrl = new shorturl({full:req.body.fullurl})
  console.log("Saving!!")
   await shortUrl.save()
    
   .then(()=>{ console.log("Inserted!!"); res.send(shortUrl.short)}).catch(error => console.log("ERROR"));
  //await shorturl.create({full:req.body.fullurl}) 
  //  if(shortUrl == null )return res.sendStatus(404);
    
})
```

**GET**

> Its making a get req but not returning any thing.Not even any error its just making get req again and again.

```
app.get('/:shortUrl',async (req,res)=>{
   try{ 
    const shortUrl = await shorturl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
   .then(()=>{
      if(shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404);
      res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
   })
  }
  catch{(error)=> console.log(error)};
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Operation \`shorturls.insertOne()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594647/mongooseerror-operation-shorturls-insertone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000)

Answer (score 1):

> Generally when there is only one connection **mongoose.connect()** is used, whereas if there is multiple instance of connection **mongoose.createConnection()** is used.

In your case, I see you have used `createConnection()`. So, you can not directly access your models through `mongoose.model`, as they were defined "in" different connections.

If you want to proceed with `createConnection()`, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect/22838614#22838614).

Else, you can simply use [mongoose.connect()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Ex:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//do not use .then() with async/await. use a try/catch block to catch errors
const connectDB = async() =>{
      try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,   });
        console.log("Database connected!"));
        return conn;  
      } catch (error) {
          //handle error
          console.error(error);
          return error;
      }
   }

// ideally you should only start the server if the the database connection was successfully established
connectDB().then(() => {
      app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
      console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
    );
});
```

**PS:**
In most simple projects, you needn't worry about specifying different read or write settings, pool sizes, separate connections to different replica servers etc., that's why `.connect` exists.

However, if you have more demanding requirements (e.g. for legal or performance reasons), you will probably have to use `.createConnection`.

Comment: okay ,but its still catching error not able to post data.

Comment: @HrithikJaiswal I updated the code with an example, does your code look like it? Btw when do you call the `connectDB()`? Are you getting the console output `Database connected!`, when starting the server?

Comment: Yes I have used .connect and I am getting Database Connected but on posting the data i am getting buffer error

Comment: @HrithikJaiswal can you update your question with the code where you call the `connectDB()` function? May be there could be an issue. (The server should only start if the database connection successful)

Comment: Okay I got the error !....well thanks for the follow up .

Comment: @HrithikJaiswal Nice! What was the issue? If this answer helped with the solution you can mark this as the accepted one. Otherwise you can post the answer yourself...

Comment: The issue was a missing catch block with calling function.

Comment: I am not able to make a get request

Comment: Hey there it was working but now I received same error again when I resumed my mongodb cluster ,please help me out !

Comment: ca you help me out!